# Does anyone know an approximate text to pixel ratio? (Java String positioning)

Tags: java, text, graphics, position

Like you see in almost all text-editing softwares, css and more, I want to position my Text with `java.awt`. My test code for this is:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // creating the frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setSize(1000, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // variables
        int x1 = 50;
        int x2 = 500;
        int y1 = 70;
        int y2 = 150;
        int y3 = 230;
        int width = 400;
        int height = 60;
        int fontsize = 40;
        String text = "This is a test";

        frame.add(new JPanel() {
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

                // borders
                g.drawRect(x1, y1, width, height); // top
                g.drawRect(x1, y2, width, height); // middle
                g.drawRect(x1, y3, width, height); // bottom
                g.drawRect(x2, y1, width, height); // left
                g.drawRect(x2, y2, width, height); // center
                g.drawRect(x2, y3, width, height); // right

                g.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.PLAIN, fontsize));

                // top
                g.drawString(text, x1 + 10, y1 + fontsize); // x1 + 10 (10 is a buffer)
                // center
                g.drawString(text, x1 + 10, y2 + fontsize + (height - fontsize) / 2);
                // bottom
                g.drawString(text, x1 + 10, y3 + height);

                // left
                g.drawString(text, x2, y1 + fontsize);
                // middle
                g.drawString(text, x2 + width / 2 - text.length() * (fontsize/5), y2 + fontsize + (height - fontsize) / 2);
                // right
                g.drawString(text, x2 + (width - text.length() * (fontsize/5)), y3 + height);

            }
        });
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Of course it kind of looks messy, but I'm working on it in an API project where I'm implementing ux features atm.

Comment: Text positioning isn't that easy as there might be a lot of situations that can change it. An easy option would be to use a monospaced font which has a fixed character width. Non-monospaced fonts might change character width based on character and even combinations (e.g. `fi` could have a width smaller than the widths of the 2 chars combined). If it's just an approximation you're after I'd try to emperically check how often the largest character (probably a `W`) would fit and base calculations on that (maybe increase that number a little since it's unlikely to get "all W"-strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FontMetrics` object of the Graphics object to get information about the Font metrics to help with determining the size of the text:

```
FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
```

See: [Measuring Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html) tutorial.

Why are you doing custom painting? Why are you not using Swing components with layout managers to manage the UI? We can't give specific advice since we don't know what the goal of your posted code is.